# One stripe account with multiple webhooks for different services

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have already integrated Stripe payments into one of my websites, and all is working great (and I'm using a unique webhook for this website).

I have just created an entirely different service through another website of mine, and am in the process of integrating Stripe on that website too.

However I have one problem, as far as I can see, I have to use the same webhook for both of my services. This won't work tho!! I really need separate webhooks for each service... is this possible?

PS: I read on Stripe's docs that every event will be sent to every webhook in the list (https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/webhooks).

Please somebody shed some light!

Comment: An entirely different service and website should have a different Stripe account, Stripe would need to separate the two from a risk / aggregation perspective.

Comment: If you add an answer with any helpful links I will accept your answer! i.e. will Stripe allow one product maker to have multiple verified accounts under his own name? I presume separate email addresses are needed and that complicates things!

Comment: in your stripe dashboard, click your name in top right and click Create new account

Comment: Perfect answer mate, thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was such a tidy fix.

Simply log in to your Stripe dashboard, and in the top right click you account name and then click 'Create New Account'.

Props to Matthew for the answer which also matches [Stripe's docs](https://stripe.com/docs/account/multiple-accounts)

> You must use separate Stripe accounts for projects, websites, or businesses that operate independently from one another.

Answer (score 1):

Log in to your Stripe Dashboard and there is a drop down option that shows your current account name on the top **left** hand side. Select it and add new account.